# Program does not run continuously

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner, user-input, filereader

I'm writing a ChatBot program where, if the ChatBot doesn't have information to answer a question by the user, it asks the user how to answer the question, and then stores it in a txt file. Later, when another question is asked, the information is retrieved from the txt file and the whole thing starts over (or at least is supposed to).

The program works, however, after one query from the user, and I press enter again for a second try, nothing happens anymore.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("Bot: Hello!! My name's HiBot! What's up?");
    System.out.print("You: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\n");
    String response = input.next();
    if (response.toLowerCase().contains("bye") || response.toLowerCase().contains("see ya")
        || response.toLowerCase().contains("gtg")) {
      System.out.println("Bot: Ok, see ya. Nice talking to you!");
    }
    processor(response);
  }

  public static void processor(String reply) {
    try {
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("convos.txt"));
      int count = 0;
      try {
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
          count++;
          if (line.toLowerCase().contains(reply.toLowerCase())) {
            try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("convos.txt"))) {
              line = lines.skip(count).findFirst().get();
              System.out.println("Bot: " + line);
              recur();
            } catch (IOException e) {
              System.out.println("Bot: Something happened \n" + e);
            }
            reader.close();
            return;
          }
          reader.close();
        }
        System.out.println("Bot: Sorry, I'm dumb. How should I reply?");
        System.out.print("You: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\n");
        String response = input.next();
        teach(reply, response);
        recur();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Bot: Something happened \n" + e);
      }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void teach(String context, String reply) {
    try {
      try {
        FileWriter learn = new FileWriter("convos.txt", true);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(learn);
        out.println(context + "\n" + reply);
        out.close();
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("Bot: Something happened \n" + e);
    }
    System.out.println("Bot: Thank you for teaching me!! I'm smarter now!");
  }

  public static void recur() {
    int trickLoop = 1;
    while (trickLoop > 0) {
      System.out.print("You: ");
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\n");
      String response = input.next();
      if (response.toLowerCase().contains("bye") || response.toLowerCase().contains("see ya")
          || response.toLowerCase().contains("gtg")) {
        System.out.println("Bot: Ok, see ya. Nice talking to you!");
        System.exit(0);
      }
      processor(response);
    }
  }
}
```

I also think that there's definitely a better way to write the code. Does anyone have any suggestions?

EDIT: I have convos.txt but I didn't show it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue1 :**

Initially file doesn't exist and you are not creating it. so it gave following error

```
Bot: Hello!! My name's HiBot! What's up?
You: hi
java.io.FileNotFoundException: convos.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

**Issue 2 :**

You are doing recursion using `recur` method which can be risky here in the case of continuous inputs as your resources will not be closed right away and can result into further resource starvation issues.
You can simply use `infinite while` loop.

**Improvement1 :**

Don't you think that once user inputs `bye/see ya/gtg` program should close ?

**Improvement2 :**

Repeated calls to `string.toLowerCase()` in main method.

**Improvement3 :**

This line `line = lines.skip(count).findFirst().get();` can result into `NoSuchElementException`

I have added improvement 2 and 3 in the below code.

Here i updated the code below which works as per your details in the question

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Bot: Hello!! My name's HiBot! What's up?");
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("You: ");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\n");
            String response = input.next();
            String lowercaseResponse = response.toLowerCase();
            if (lowercaseResponse.contains("bye") || lowercaseResponse.contains("see ya")
                    || lowercaseResponse.contains("gtg")) {
                System.out.println("Bot: Ok, see ya. Nice talking to you!");
            }
            processor(response);
        }
    }

    public static void processor(String reply) {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            File file = new File("convos.txt");
            if (file.createNewFile())
                System.out.println("Conversations file created");
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file.getName()));
            int count = 0;
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                count++;
                if (line.toLowerCase().contains(reply.toLowerCase())) {
                    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("convos.txt"))) {
                        line = lines.skip(count).findFirst().map(Object::toString).orElse("I don't know how to respond");
                        System.out.println("Bot: " + line);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println("Bot: Something happened while reading conversation file \n" + e);
                    }
                    reader.close();
                    return;
                }
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            reader.close();
            System.out.println("Bot: Sorry, I'm dumb. How should I reply?");
            System.out.print("You: ");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\n");
            String response = input.next();
            teach(reply, response);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Bot: File not found \n" + e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Bot: Something happened \n" + e);
        } finally {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Bot: Something happened while closing the file reader \n" + e);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void teach(String context, String reply) {
        try {
            try {
                FileWriter learn = new FileWriter("convos.txt", true);
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(learn);
                out.println(context + "\n" + reply);
                out.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Bot: Something happened \n" + e);
        }
        System.out.println("Bot: Thank you for teaching me!! I'm smarter now!");
    }
}
```

Output : `For the first time`

```
Bot: Hello!! My name's HiBot! What's up?
You: hi
Conversations file created
Bot: Sorry, I'm dumb. How should I reply?
You: hello
Bot: Thank you for teaching me!! I'm smarter now!
You: 
hi
Bot: hello
You:
```

Output : `When Convos.txt is created already`

```
Bot: Hello!! My name's HiBot! What's up?
You: hi
Bot: hello
You: hi
Bot: hello
You: hi
Bot: hello
You:
```

Let me know if i missed anything.

Comment: It still gives me the problem:

`Bot: Hello!! My name's HiBot! What's up?
You: Hello!
Bot: Sorry, I'm dumb. How should I reply?
You: Hey! How's it going?
Bot: Thank you for teaching me!! I'm smarter now!
You: You are cool!`

And then I press enter, and nothing happens.
I've tried using infinite loops already.

Comment: What should happen when you press enter ?

Comment: The whole process should redo. I say "You are cool!", and the Bot either gives me a response or asks me what to say.

Comment: It still doesn't work. See, try teaching the bot something, and then say something to it. That's when it stops working.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this question because someone edited the question.

Here's one test run.  The "convos.txt" file exists and has a couple of response / reply text lines.

```
Bot: Hello! My name's HiBot! What's up?
You: hi
Bot: Hi
You: how are you
Bot: Fine.  How are you?
You: Good
Bot: Sorry, I'm ignorant. How should I reply?
You: That's good to hear.
Bot: Thank you for teaching me a new reply! I'm smarter now!
You: bye
Bot: Ok, see ya. Nice talking to you!
```

I eliminated the multiple `System.in` `Scanner` instances.  In the reorganized code, I only needed one `Scanner` instance.  There should only be one `System.in` `Scanner` instance in your code.

I created a separate `ResponseMap` class to hold a `HashMap` for the response / reply text.

I created a separate `FileHandler` class to handle the reading and writing of the text file.  I read the file into the `Map` once in the beginning.  I write the `Map` into the file once at the end.  Even when you have 10,000 response / reply lines, the entire file should easily fit into memory.

Because I made the `Map` value a `List` of `String` instances, you can manually create multiple replies for the same response.  This adds a bit of variety to the chatbot.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class ChatbotExample {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ChatbotExample().runChatbot();
    }
    
    public void runChatbot() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] exitResponses = { "bye", "see ya", "gtg" };
        List<String> exitList = Arrays.asList(exitResponses);
        
        boolean running = true;
        System.out.println("Bot: Hello! My name's HiBot! What's up?");
        
        ResponseMap responseMap = new ResponseMap();
        FileHandler fileHandler = new FileHandler(responseMap);
        fileHandler.readFile();
        
        while (running) {
            System.out.print("You: ");
            String response = scanner.nextLine();
            String lowercaseResponse = response.toLowerCase();
            if (exitList.contains(lowercaseResponse)) {
                System.out.println("Bot: Ok, see ya. Nice talking to you!");
                running = false;
            } else {
                generateReply(scanner, responseMap, lowercaseResponse);
            }
        }
        
        fileHandler.writeFile();
        scanner.close();
    }

    private void generateReply(Scanner scanner, ResponseMap responseMap, 
            String lowercaseResponse) {
        String text = responseMap.getResponse(lowercaseResponse);
        if (text == null) {
            System.out.println("Bot: Sorry, I'm ignorant. How should I reply?");
            System.out.print("You: ");
            String reply = scanner.nextLine();
            responseMap.addResponse(lowercaseResponse, reply);
            System.out.println("Bot: Thank you for teaching me a new reply! "
                    + "I'm smarter now!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Bot: " +  text);
        }
    }
    
    public class FileHandler {
        
        private final File file;
        
        private final ResponseMap responseMap;
        
        private final String separator;
        
        public FileHandler(ResponseMap responseMap) {
            this.responseMap = responseMap;
            this.separator = " ;;; ";
            this.file = new File("convos.txt");
            createFile(this.file);
        }

        private void createFile(File file) {
            try {
                if (file.createNewFile()) {
                    System.out.println("Conversations file created");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void readFile() {
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new FileReader(file));
                
                String line = reader.readLine();
                while (line != null) {
                    String[] parts = line.split(separator);
                    responseMap.addResponse(parts[0], parts[1]);
                    line = reader.readLine();
                }
                
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        
        public void writeFile() {
            try {
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file, false);
                PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(writer);
                Map<String, List<String>> responses = responseMap.getResponses();
                Set<String> responseSet = responses.keySet();
                Iterator<String> iterator = responseSet.iterator();
                
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    String key = iterator.next();
                    List<String> text = responses.get(key);
                    for (String reply : text) {
                        String s = key + separator + reply;
                        output.println(s);
                    }
                }
                
                output.flush();
                output.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    public class ResponseMap {
        
        private final Map<String, List<String>> responses;
        
        private final Random random;
        
        public ResponseMap() {
            this.responses = new HashMap<>();
            this.random = new Random();
        }
        
        public Map<String, List<String>> getResponses() {
            return responses;
        }

        public String getResponse(String key) {
            List<String> possibleResponses = responses.get(key);
            if (possibleResponses == null) {
                return null;
            } else {
                int index = random.nextInt(possibleResponses.size());
                return possibleResponses.get(index);
            }
        }
        
        public void addResponse(String key, String text) {
            List<String> possibleResponses = responses.get(key);
            if (possibleResponses == null) {
                possibleResponses = new ArrayList<>();
                responses.put(key, possibleResponses);
            }
            possibleResponses.add(text);
        }
    }

}
```